# Reactive form will not create a new entity because of many to one relation

Tags: angular, spring-boot

Im having issues getting an Angular reactive form to post a new entity to my spring boot back end, i can see what the issue is but im fresh to Angular and Spring boot so im having difficulty implementing a solution.

In short ive modelled a car park, it has buildings and floors, when i attempt to add a new floor to a building i am faced with the following exception;

```
not-null property references a null or transient value : com.reslink.models.ParkingFloor.parkingBuilding
```

I understand the exception and what its telling me, the payload does not contain the parkingBuilding element, as a solution ive attempted to pass in a stringify(building) which appears to provide the backend the expected payload but the backend then begins to throw the  exception;

```
JSON parse error: Cannot coerce empty String ("") to `com.reslink.models.ParkingBuilding` value (but could if coercion was enabled using `CoercionConfig`)
```

Again i understand the exception but i feel like im beginning going down a blind rabbit hole of experiments to help me understand Angular and spring boot. Can someone help point me in the right direction because i feel like im not grasping some fundamental concepts here.

```
package com.reslink.models;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity(name = "parking_buildings")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class ParkingBuilding {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long building_id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String building_name;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String postcode;
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private int max_floors;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String owner_name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parkingBuilding")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties({"parkingBuilding", "parkingFloors", "parkingSpace"})
    @OrderBy("floor_number")
    private Set<ParkingFloor> parkingFloors;

    public ParkingBuilding() {
    }

    public long getBuilding_id() {
        return building_id;
    }

    public void setBuilding_id(long building_id) {
        this.building_id = building_id;
    }

    public String getBuilding_name() {
        return building_name;
    }

    public void setBuilding_name(String building_name) {
        this.building_name = building_name;
    }

    public String getPostcode() {
        return postcode;
    }

    public void setPostcode(String postcode) {
        this.postcode = postcode;
    }

    public int getMax_floors() {
        return max_floors;
    }

    public void setMax_floors(int max_floors) {
        this.max_floors = max_floors;
    }

    public String getOwner_name() {
        return owner_name;
    }

    public void setOwner_name(String owner_name) {
        this.owner_name = owner_name;
    }

    public Set<ParkingFloor> getParkingFloors() {
        return parkingFloors;
    }

    public void setParkingFloors(Set<ParkingFloor> parkingFloors) {
        this.parkingFloors = parkingFloors;
    }

}
```

My floor model

```
package com.reslink.models;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDelete;
import org.hibernate.annotations.OnDeleteAction;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "parking_floors")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})

public class ParkingFloor {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long floor_id;

    private int floor_number;
    private int max_height_inches;
    private boolean is_covered;
    private boolean is_disabled_access;

    @ManyToOne
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "building_id", insertable = true, updatable = true, nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("parkingFloors")
    private ParkingBuilding parkingBuilding;

    //ToDo correct pluralisation

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parkingFloor")
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("parkingFloor")
    @OrderBy("space_number")
    private Set<ParkingSpace> parkingSpace;

    public ParkingFloor() {
    }

    public long getFloor_id() {
        return floor_id;
    }

    public void setFloor_id(long floor_id) {
        this.floor_id = floor_id;
    }

    public int getFloor_number() {
        return floor_number;
    }

    public void setFloor_number(int floor_number) {
        this.floor_number = floor_number;
    }

    public int getMax_height_inches() {
        return max_height_inches;
    }

    public void setMax_height_inches(int max_height_inches) {
        this.max_height_inches = max_height_inches;
    }

    public boolean isIs_covered() {
        return is_covered;
    }

    public void setIs_covered(boolean is_covered) {
        this.is_covered = is_covered;
    }

    public boolean isIs_disabled_access() {
        return is_disabled_access;
    }

    public void setIs_disabled_access(boolean is_disabled_access) {
        this.is_disabled_access = is_disabled_access;
    }

    public ParkingBuilding getParkingBuilding() {
        return parkingBuilding;
    }

    public void setParkingBuilding(ParkingBuilding parkingBuilding) {
        this.parkingBuilding = parkingBuilding;
    }

    public Set<ParkingSpace> getParkingSpace() {
        return parkingSpace;
    }

    public void setParkingSpace(Set<ParkingSpace> parkingSpace) {
        this.parkingSpace = parkingSpace;
    }

}
```

My building controller

```
package com.reslink.controllers;

import com.reslink.models.ParkingBuilding;
import com.reslink.models.ParkingFloor;
import com.reslink.repositories.ParkingBuildingRepository;
import com.reslink.repositories.ParkingFloorRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/parkingbuildings")
public class ParkingBuildingController {

    @Autowired
    private ParkingBuildingRepository parkingBuildingRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public List<ParkingBuilding> list() {return parkingBuildingRepository.findAll();}

    @GetMapping
    @RequestMapping("{id}")
    public ParkingBuilding get(@PathVariable Long id) {
        return  parkingBuildingRepository.getById(id);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public ParkingBuilding create(@RequestBody final ParkingBuilding parkingBuilding) {
        return parkingBuildingRepository.saveAndFlush(parkingBuilding);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
        parkingBuildingRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ParkingBuilding update(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody ParkingBuilding parkingBuilding) {
        ParkingBuilding existingParkingBuilding = parkingBuildingRepository.getById(id);
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(parkingBuilding, existingParkingBuilding, "building_id");
        return parkingBuildingRepository.saveAndFlush(existingParkingBuilding);
    }
}
```

My floor controller

```
package com.reslink.controllers;

import com.reslink.models.ParkingFloor;
import com.reslink.repositories.ParkingFloorRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/parkingfloors")
public class ParkingFloorController {

    @Autowired
    private ParkingFloorRepository parkingFloorRepository;

    @GetMapping
    public List<ParkingFloor> list() {return parkingFloorRepository.findAll();}

    @GetMapping
    @RequestMapping("{id}")
    public ParkingFloor get(@PathVariable Long id) {return  parkingFloorRepository.getById(id);}

    @PostMapping
    public ParkingFloor create(@RequestBody final ParkingFloor parkingFloor) {
        return parkingFloorRepository.saveAndFlush(parkingFloor);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
    public void delete(@PathVariable Long id) {
        parkingFloorRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    public ParkingFloor update(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody ParkingFloor parkingFloor) {
        ParkingFloor existingParkingFloor = parkingFloorRepository.getById(id);
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(parkingFloor, existingParkingFloor, "floor_id");
        return parkingFloorRepository.saveAndFlush(existingParkingFloor);
    }
}
```

And lastly my Angular component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ParkingService } from 'src/app/services/parking.service';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { stringify } from 'querystring';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-addparkingfloor',
  templateUrl: './addparkingfloor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./addparkingfloor.component.css']
})
export class AddparkingfloorComponent implements OnInit {

  public building;
  floorform: FormGroup;
  validMessage: string = "";

  constructor(private parkingService: ParkingService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.getBuilding(this.route.snapshot.params['id'])

    this.floorform = new FormGroup({
      parkingBuilding: new FormControl(stringify(this.building)),
      floor_number: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      max_height_inches: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      is_covered: new FormControl('', Validators.required),
      is_disabled_access: new FormControl('', Validators.required)
    });

  }
  submitFloor() {
    if (this.floorform.valid) {
      this.validMessage = "Floor has been added";
      this.parkingService.createFloor(this.floorform.value).subscribe(
        data => {
          this.floorform.reset();
          return true;
        },
        error => {
          return throwError(error);

        }
      )
    } else {
      this.validMessage = "fill form before submitting";
    }
  }

  getBuilding(id: number) {
    this.parkingService.getBuilding(id).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.building = data;
      },
      err => console.error(err),
      () => console.log('floor loaded')
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a mistake due to a poor understanding of spring boot. Id attempted to pass the reference to the building object from angular to spring boot many different ways. In the end i realized that all i really needed to do was to pass the parent object reference via the uri to the backend then use a buildingRespository to findById using the value from the uri to the add the building to the floor object before i flushAndSaved the floor entity.